# Skype 12.04 doesn't open anymore

Tags: dell, skype, webcam

Skype doesn't work anymore. It used to work fine. Then the Webcam stopped working I tried to fix this and ever since it just wont open at all.

My computer is a Dell 1525 Intel Core 2 Duo with a built in webcam

Comment: Is it Skype 4? have you tried doing the command line way?

Answer (score 2):

Does it warn you that you have `[...] unmet dependencies` ?
I had a similar issue, and tried reinstall. However, the install failed. I tried to update my repositories and upgrade. If you try the same, and upgrading fails run this command in your terminal and try run update + upgrade again.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no luck either dude keep trying to update as well and nothing

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in 11.10, used this, upgraded to 12.04 and it still works.

Paste in Terminal  to create a blank file :

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/skype
```

(that if gedit is your text editor)

There, paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

save and close. Now to make the file executable, copy and paste the following line into Terminal.

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/skype
```

Enter. Start skype

Thanks to [this source](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/219), including the change suggested by that website's user JuliusP0pp in his comment there

Comment: thanks dude ive done this and still no luck nothing seems to happen i try to open skype and it just wont respond and open

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I just got it fixed thanks for all your help it turned out I had to uninstall everything from Skype by purging it. and installing it from the Skype website now it opens and the webcam even works on it thanks guys 
so

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
sudo apt-get purge skype-bin    
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then reinstall Skype 4 from the Skype website and Bingo!

Comment: mark it as definitive answer